# Extract strings with Regex in gsub

Tags: regex, r

I try to use regex to extract string from R source code.
I have this string :

```
x<-c("    stop(\"You forgot to specify the correct answer on a multiple choice question!\")",
"stop(\"this value\",var,\"is ok\")",
"stop(args=anything,message=\"hi how are you\")",
"PLOP(args=anything,message=\"DONT WANT THIS ONE\")",
 "    BIDUL(\"DONT WANT THIS ONE\")",
 "stop(args=anything,message=\"THIS ONE IS OK\"); BIDUL(\"DONT WANT THIS ONE\")"
)
```

I would like to obtain :

```
 result<- c("You forgot to specify the correct answer on a multiple choice question!","this value","is ok","hi how are you","THIS ONE IS OK")
```

I tried a lot of thing with gsub, but not sure what I do. 
can you please help me ?

Regards

Comment: how gsub would return two sub elements from single element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
library(stringr)
unlist(str_extract_all(x, perl('(?<=\")[^,\"]+(?=\")')))
#[1] "You forgot to specify the correct answer on a multiple choice question!"
#[2] "this value"                                                             
#[3] "is ok"                                                                  
#[4] "hi how are you"
```

#### Update

Based on the new 'x'

```
unlist(str_extract_all(x[grep('stop', x)], perl('(?<=\")[^,\"]+(?=\")')))
#[1] "You forgot to specify the correct answer on a multiple choice question!"
#[2] "this value"                                                             
#[3] "is ok"                                                                  
#[4] "hi how are you"
```

#### Update2

With the changes in 'x'

```
 v1 <- str_extract(x[grep('stop', x)], perl('(?<=stop)[^)]+(?=\\))'))
 unlist(str_extract_all(v1, perl('(?<=\")[^,\"]+(?=\")')))
 #[1] "You forgot to specify the correct answer on a multiple choice question!"
 #[2] "this value"                                                    
 #[3] "is ok"                                                         
 #[4] "hi how are you"                                                
 #[5] "THIS ONE IS OK"
```

Comment: Or may be the `regmatches`.  Haven't tried the `gsub`.  Anyway, you are the regex boss. :-)

Comment: @AvinashRaj  I am using only R, so may be with the practise, I got a bit skilled.   You seem to know a lot of languages.  I wish to learn python, Java etc.  Any tips? Thanks.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I change a little my question to be more precise ( I just want to get string in stop function). Can you have a lot ?

Comment: @Bakalegum Updated the post, Please check if it helps

Comment: @akrun, yes, but this should also work if stop() and BIDUL() are in the same sentence.. I uptaded the post to show you. Regards

Comment: @Bakalegum Do you have `;` delimiter between `stop()` `BIDUL()` in cases where they are in the same sentence?

Comment: @akrun not always.. sorry :p . I think I need to catch only all sentences inside stop( ).

Comment: @Bakalegum Updated with a possible option.  Hope it works for you.